Makefile - Header files not found even after inclusions
I am porting nRF8001 library to a stm32 mcu and in the makefile no matter how I include the header files it's not recognizing the path. I am not sure what's wrong with this makefile
TARGET=main
EXECUTABLE=main.elf
BINARYOUT=main.bin
# STLINK=~/Downloads/stlink
LIBPATH=C\:/Users/gkowshik/OneDrive\ -\ PragmatIC\ Semiconductor\ Ltd/Documents/kowshik_work/wearables_demo/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Lib
# COMPILER=C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.1/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.0.202305231506/tools/bin

# CC=$(COMPILER)/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe
# LD=$(COMPILER)/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe
# AR=$(COMPILER)/arm-none-eabi-ar.exe
# AS=$(COMPILER)/arm-none-eabi-as.exe
# CP=$(COMPILER)/arm-none-eabi-objcopy.exe
# OD=$(COMPILER)/arm-none-eabi-objdump.exe

CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
LD=arm-none-eabi-gcc
AR=arm-none-eabi-ar
AS=arm-none-eabi-as
CP=arm-none-eabi-objcopy
OD=arm-none-eabi-objdump

BIN=$(CP) -O ihex

DEFS = -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER -DSTM32L1xx -DSTM32L1XX_MD -DHSE_VALUE=8000000
STARTUP = $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L1xx/Source/Templates/gcc_ride7/startup_stm32l151cbuxa.s

MCU = cortex-m3
MCFLAGS = -mcpu=$(MCU) -mthumb -mlittle-endian -mfloat-abi=soft -std=c99
STM32_INCLUDES = -I$(LIBPATH)/Libraries/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L1xx/Include/ \
    -I$(LIBPATH)/Libraries/CMSIS/Include/ \
    -I$(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/inc/ \
    -I./inc/ \
    -I./inc/BLE/

OPTIMIZE = -O0

CFLAGS = $(MCFLAGS) $(OPTIMIZE) $(DEFS) -I. -I$(STM32_INCLUDES) -Wl,-T,stm32_flash.ld
AFLAGS = $(MCFLAGS)
#-mapcs-float use float regs. small increase in code size

SRC = ./src/main.c \
    ./src/millis.c \
    ./src/usart.c \
    ./src/spi.c \
    ./src/debug.c \
    ./src/stm32l1xx_it.c \
    ./src/system_stm32l1xx.c \
    ./src/BLE/io_support.c \
    ./src/BLE/acilib.c \
    ./src/BLE/aci_queue.c \
    ./src/BLE/aci_setup.c \
    ./src/BLE/hal_aci_tl.c \
    ./src/BLE/lib_aci.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/misc.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_adc.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_crc.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_aes.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_dac.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_dbgmcu.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_dma.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_exti.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_flash_ramfunc.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_flash.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_fsmc.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_gpio.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_i2c.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_iwdg.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_lcd.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_opamp.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_pwr.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_rcc.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_rtc.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_sdio.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_spi.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_syscfg.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_tim.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_usart.c \
    $(LIBPATH)/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32l1xx_wwdg.c

OBJDIR = .
OBJ = $(SRC:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
STARTUP_OBJ = $(STARTUP:%.s=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(EXECUTABLE)
    $(CP) -O ihex $(EXECUTABLE) $(TARGET).hex
    $(CP) -O binary $(EXECUTABLE) $(BINARYOUT)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJ) $(STARTUP_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ) $(STARTUP_OBJ) -lm -lc -lnosys -o $(EXECUTABLE)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.s
    $(AS) $(AFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*.o $(TARGET) $(EXECUTABLE) $(BINARYOUT) $(TARGET).hex


I have ensured that the header files do exist in the same directory are added into the makefile during compilation. Here's the compilation error I get
kowshik@KG01LW0637:/mnt/c/Users/gkowshik/OneDrive - PragmatIC Semiconductor Ltd/Documents/kowshik_work/wearables_demo/nrf8001-stm32f4$ make clean && make all
rm -f ./*.o main main.elf main.bin main.hex
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -mlittle-endian -mfloat-abi=soft -std=c99 -O0 -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER -DSTM32L1xx -DSTM32L1XX_MD -DHSE_VALUE=8000000 -I. -I./ -I""C\:/Users/gkowshik/OneDrive\ -\ PragmatIC\ Semiconductor\ Ltd/Documents/kowshik_work/wearables_demo/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Lib"/Libraries/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L1xx/Include/" -I""C\:/Users/gkowshik/OneDrive\ -\ PragmatIC\ Semiconductor\ Ltd/Documents/kowshik_work/wearables_demo/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Lib"/Libraries/CMSIS/Include/" -I""C\:/Users/gkowshik/OneDrive\ -\ PragmatIC\ Semiconductor\ Ltd/Documents/kowshik_work/wearables_demo/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Lib"/Libraries/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/inc/" -I./inc/ -I./inc/BLE/ -Wl,-T,stm32_flash.ld -c src/main.c -o src/main.o
src/main.c:4:10: fatal error: stm32l1xx.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <stm32l1xx.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:94: src/main.o] Error 1

If I change the inclusion in the main.c to the below way it is able to see the file, However I can't take this approach as there are tens of header files and hundreds of code lines where includes are done hence we took the makefile approach of including it once and we can directly call it, is there something wrong with the way my path is declared? i.e., 'OneDrive ' has many space in it. Could that be an issue?
#include "../../STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Lib/Libraries/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L1xx/Include/stm32l1xx.h

Tried to change the path of the folder(Instead of long 'OneDrive ' folder with spaces) but still the same error occurs.

see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

You define STM32_INCLUDES but then never use it anywhere.

It is really hard to use paths with spaces in them with make.  Your make output seems to indicate that that is at least part of your problem.  You may not be able to rename that folder, but you could move or copy the needed contents to somewhere else, or perhaps arrange for and use an alternative, no-spaces path to the same thing.

@pmacfarlane oops I forgot to add the below lines in my post
AFLAGS = $(MCFLAGS)``` 

I am using these CFLAGS in the recepies

@JohnBollinger I tried that as well, I moved into a directory called "C:\test" but still getting same errors

@Hako -I$(STM32_INCLUDES) feels like an error, because STM32_INCLUDES starts with -I. So it will expand to -I-I.... Just use $(STM32_INCLUDES) with no -I.

@pmacfarlane That's a good catch definitely an issue. I changed it, but still nothing

You can see the command line that calls GCC, and it include this suspicious option: -I""C\:/Users/gkowshik/OneDrive\ -\ PragmatIC\ Semiconductor\ Ltd/Documents/kowshik_work/wearables_demo/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Lib"/Libraries/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L1xx/Include/" because of multiple quotation marks and backslashes. You can experiment with the command until you find the right way to express the include paths. Only then implement it in the Makefile.

@thebusybee I have removed the quotes, moved to a shorter file path and tried again, see my output
src/main.c:4:10: fatal error: stm32l1xx.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <stm32l1xx.h>```

And changing C\: to C:? Is the header to include actually there?

@thebusybee Changing the C: doesn't proceed to compiling the c files, it fails with the error "Makefile:91: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop."

Yes, sure. Try the command as such on the command line. Reduce the issue's complexity by finding the correct compiler call first, only then proceed to implement your Makefile, as I wrote before.

Nothing worked, except for one trick. I used wsl on windows, then used /home/use path to store my library files and then gave that path. Worked like a charm. Maybe I should switch to Cmake for windows compatibility of paths etc., it's very hard in traditional makefiles.

One trick worked. I used WSL on Windows, then used the /home/usr path to store my library files and then gave that path. Worked like a charm. Maybe I should switch to CMAKE for Windows compatibility of paths etc.; it's very hard in traditional makefiles.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
